# Regexp TCL unable to get entire word containing character

Tags: regex, tcl, regex-greedy

I'm new to TCL and I need to use regexp in TLC to pull all numbers that have 5 in them

I put together a successful but I can't use it because it lsearch :

```
set x "55 6 90 5 89 105 7 85 191"  
puts [lsearch -all -inline -regexp $x {5} ]
```

this results in:

> 55 5 105 85

this is where I want to get to using regexp

This is the closest I could get:

```
puts [regexp -all -inline {9.+} $x]
```

I get the result:

> {90 5 89 105 7 85 191 }

which shows extra words that don't belong there

Comment: May I ask why you want to use `regexp` instead of `lsearch` if `lsearch` is working fine? Why can't you use `lsearch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `9.+` will match the first 9 in a string and the longest possible sequence of one or more characters following, so until the end of the string. (It won't match if the first 9 is the last character in the string, though, because of the requirement for at least one following character). If you want to match just the individual *words* in the string with a 9 in them, you can use sequences of 0 or more non-whitespace characters bracketing a literal 9 (Or 5, or whatever):

```
% regexp -all -inline {\S*9\S*} $x
90 89 191
% regexp -all -inline {\S*5\S*} $x
55 5 105 85
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match only numbers that contain 9, you can match optional digits around the number and use word boundaries to prevent a partial match. The `.` will match any character and will match too much.

```php
\m\d*9\d*\M
```

- `\m` Word boundary for start of word
- `\d*9\d*` Match `9` between optional digits
- `\M` Word boundary for end of word

For example

```
set x "55 6 90 5 89 105 7 85 191"
regexp -all -inline {\m\d*9\d*\M} $x
```

Output

```
90 89 191
```